# fedora 27 running on lenovo ideapad 700 no touchpad access

Tags: linux, fedora, touchpad

My wife has a fairly new Lenovo Ideapad 700 on which I have installed a pretty vanilla Fedora 27.

Everything was running fine until a few weeks ago when her touchpad stopped working.

Running `libinput list-devices` doesn't show anything that I recognize as a touchpad.

At this point I'm ready to take it to the dealer to see if it's hardware/warranty case, but the first thing they will do is reinstall Windows, meaning a lot of extra work for me.

Is there anything I should try before taking this step?

Comment: She didn't disable it through a keyboard combination?  But most give some kind of signal (screen, led) to indicate that the touchpad is disabled.

Comment: The f5 key gives a visual cue that touchpad has been enabled/disabled, but this has no impact on behavior.